# How to create a stack of resources in Android from the asset and/or res folders?

Tags: java, android, resources, stack, assets

Here is [the thread](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3380/how-do-i-load-chunks-of-data-from-an-assest-manager-during-a-loading-screen) that I read about making a stack of resources from AssetManager in Android.

What does it mean to "creating a stack of resources from AssetManager?" Do I have to use:

```
Stack stack = new Stack();
stack.push(this.getAssets());
```

Or something? If anyone can give hints, I appreciate it. If the question is not specific enough, please post in the comments about it, and I'll improve the question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Stack is just a collection of Objects, the same as an array, ArrayList, Collection, etc.

The benefit of using a Stack is that you can simply `push(Object o)` objects in to the Stack to add them to the collection, and `pop()` objects off the Stack when you want to get them back. A Stack can grow to any size.

You would probably need to do something like this...

```
Stack stack = new Stack();
AssetManager assets = this.getAssets();
String[] assetLocations = assets.list();

for (int i=0;i<assetLocations.length;i++){
    byte[] asset = loadAssetFromStream(assetLocations[i]); // you need to write this
    stack.push(asset);
}
```

AssetManager has an `open()` method for reading the assets - you'll probably need to read each asset into memory (like a `byte[]` array or an actual `Object`) and then push each object into the stack.

Refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html for more information

Comment: If I load a file from InputStream into an array of bytes, does that also mean the size of the loaded file is the size of the byte array times 8?

Comment: No, I think you're getting mixed up with bits and bytes. The `byte[]` array would be the same size as the original file (as files are typically measured in bytes), unless for some reason the file is compressed (pretty certain assets aren't compressed individually). You can use the `openFd(String)` method on `AssetManager` to get an `AssetFileDescriptor`, which you can then call `getLength()` to get the size of the file.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! Along with that, I should also thank you for giving me more helpful hints. I never knew how to get the total size of the file until now. AssetFileDescriptor.getLength() really fit my needs.